# How can I sort only some parts of the array in a specific order in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So let's assume I have an array `array{12, 10, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8}` in descending order.
I want to sort the numbers that can be divided by 2 but not with 4 in ascending order at the end of the array, the numbers that are divided by 4 sorted at the start of the array in descending order and the rest in the middle(no specific order). For my example, after the transformation it should look something like this:
`array{12, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10}`. Is there any way I can do this efficiently? c++ language.
Sorry for any misspelling.

Comment: Use `std::sort` and supply a *predicate* comparison lambda that encodes your ordering criteria.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::sort` and `std::partition`

Comment: @NathanOliver I looked up std::partition but I don't understand what is it supposed to do.

Comment: It allows you to partition a data set based on some predicate.  It will move all of the elements where the predicate is true to the front of the array and leave the rest at the end.  The you can sort that front section of the array to get the order you want.

Comment: @AdrianHEY `std::partition` is used to partition your container in two. One side of the container holds elements for which a certain condition is true, and the other holds the elements for which it does not. It looks like you want to first partition your container twice, since you want 3 sections. Once your container is properly partitioned, you can sort each partition individually according to that partition's requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's organize the requirement.

The required order is:

1. Numbers that are divided by 4
2. Others
3. Numbers that can be divided by 2 but not with 4

Among the numbers with same priority according to the above rule, the numbers should be

1. Descending order
2. No specific order
3. Ascending order

Let's implement this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void test(std::vector<int> array) { // intensionally passed by value
    std::cout << "before sorting:";
    for (int v : array) std::cout << ' ' << v;
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), [](int a, int b) -> bool {
        int pa, pb; // priority a/b

        if (a % 4 == 0) pa = 1;
        else if (a % 2 == 0) pa = 3;
        else pa = 2;

        if (b % 4 == 0) pb = 1;
        else if (b % 2 == 0) pb = 3;
        else pb = 2;

        // if the priority differs, sort according to the priority
        if (pa != pb) return pa < pb;
        // if both can be divided by 4, sort in descending order
        if (pa == 1) return b < a;
        // if both can be divided by 2 but not with 4, sort in ascending order
        if (pa == 3) return a < b;
        // no specific order for the rest
        return false;
    });

    std::cout << "after  sorting:";
    for (int v : array) std::cout << ' ' << v;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> array = {12, 10, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8};
    std::vector<int> array2 = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    test(array);
    std::cout << '\n';
    test(array2);
    return 0;
}
```

[Example output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l2ZXYxdedIBtBpMv):

```
before sorting: 12 10 10 9 8 8 8
after  sorting: 12 8 8 8 9 10 10

before sorting: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
after  sorting: 8 4 9 7 5 3 1 2 6 10
```

Comment: It workd! Thank you so much for the answer. Just 1 thing.. what is in the std::sort after arra.begin(), array.end()? also the little arrow ->. Never heard of those before

Comment: The whole of `[](int a, int b) -> bool { ... }` is a [lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11/7627218#7627218)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [MikeCAT's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68409226/2610810), C++20 adds a variation of `sort` which accepts a *projection*, i.e. a function to apply to each element before we pass it to the comparison functor.

This utilises the fact that `std::tuple` has a predefined `<` that orders the tuple by each member in turn.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::tuple<int, int> my_order(int val) {
    if (val % 4 == 0) return { 1, -val };
    else if (val % 2 == 0) return { 3, val };
    else return { 2, 0 };
}

void test(std::vector<int> array) { // intensionally passed by value
    std::cout << "before sorting:";
    for (int v : array) std::cout << ' ' << v;
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::ranges::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), std::ranges::less{}, my_order);

    std::cout << "after  sorting:";
    for (int v : array) std::cout << ' ' << v;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> array = {12, 10, 10, 9, 8, 8, 8};
    std::vector<int> array2 = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    test(array);
    std::cout << '\n';
    test(array2);
    return 0;
}
```